# Is it possible to capture the screen and send it to google drive via pydrive?

Tags: python, screen-capture

I want me to capture the screen and send a file to google drive every 10 minutes.

**I have already configured pydrive and got client_secrets.json, settings.yaml, credentials.json**

Comment: asking for recommendations is off topic. please research ways to capture the screen. -- opencv can't capture the screen. you need another library for that. -- please take the [tour] and review [ask]